# How to validate a button click on client side

Tags: javascript, web

Let's say, i have a website and it has one button: `click me`, and also a counter which counts how many times people clicked on the button.
The thing is, how to validate if the clicker is a real person, that he clicked only once e.t.c. ?
Ip's can be changed. Also, it's not a good choise to make a whole account system for a single button.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use Google analytics

Comment: I am afraid that without account system and ip checking, your only viable option is some kind of crystal ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- You can save the count in the cache to make it accessible on the backend side.
2.- In the Frontend you cannot access to the IP, so you won't be able to check at that level.
3.- Maybe what you're looking for is a button with a Post in a login website, then everytime the button is clicked you can send the post with the user information and saved.
4.- To validate if'¡ it is a human you can use [Google Captcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible).

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I'm afraid i didn't quite understand point 3. Can you rephrase, please?

Comment: Create a POST endpoint, then with a login user, make that the button send a request with the current User information, is the best way to know really which user click the button and how many times.

Comment: So, that button creates an account which has his IP, captcha status and things, so i can validate him without having the user to actually create an account?

Comment: You will have to find a way to create this account, base on the browser information that for security reasons is not much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Invisible ReCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible). It's not 100% reliable when it comes to detect bots (it has been proven mutliple times by the past) but still very efficient.

However, to detect if a single person have clicked only once, there is no viable solution I think. You can maybe add a cookie and check if the cookie exists but it can be easily bypassed by simply deleting the said cookie.

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate a unique device, you can store MAC, IP address, and User Agent.  Of course, all those can both be spoofed to allow multiple clicks.  That solution would also limit to one person per device, which may not be your intent.  Storing User Agent with the MAC address is more difficult to get around than a cookie (that can be deleted).

You can eliminate the most common bots by their user agent, or you can use a CAPTCHA.

You authenticate persons by email account or OpenID, but I assume you want to make clicking the button as easy as possible.

Comment: MAC adress is a smart idea. Thanks!